# Stone-Weierstrass vanishing at one point

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Assume $\mathrm{E}$ is a compact metric space; that $\mathscr{A}$ is an algebra in $\mathscr{C}_{\Bbb R}(\mathrm{E})$ such that $\mathscr{A}$ separates points and there is a point $x \in \mathrm{E}$ such that for every $f \in \mathscr{A}$  it happens that $f(x) = 0.$ By virtue of the separation of points, $x$ is the only point satisfying this condition. My intuitions tells me that $\overline{\mathscr{A}}$ *ought* to be all continuous $f:\mathrm{E} \to \Bbb R$ such that $f$ is continuous and $f(x) = 0.$ My idea is to take such $f,$ then take a small open neighbourhood $\mathrm{V}$ of $x$ on where $|f|$ is tiny and then approximate $f$ outside $\mathrm{V}$ by some $g$ in $\overline{\mathscr{A}}.$ The problem is, how to control $g$ inside $\mathrm{V}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume the field is $\mathbb R.$ Define $\mathscr A'= \{ f+c: f \in \mathscr A, c\in \mathbb R\}.$ Then $\mathscr A'$ is a subalgebra of $C(E)$ that separates points and vanishes nowhere. By Stone Weierstrass, $\mathscr A'$ is dense in $C(E).$ Suppose $f\in C(E)$ and $f(x) = 0.$ Then there exists a sequence $f_n + c_n \in \mathscr A'$  such that $f_n + c_n\to f$ in the $\sup $ norm. Because $f(x) = 0$ and $f_n(x) = 0$ for all $n,$ we must have $c_n \to 0.$ But if $c_n \to 0,$ then $f_n \to f$ in the $\sup $ norm. Thus $f$ is the uniform limit of a sequence in $\mathscr A$ as desired.

Comment: I think I was attacking the problem from the wrong perspective. Thank you!